# Kernel panic during shutdown: "System is deadlocked on memory"

Tags: kernel-panic, out-of-memory

I am running Debian Buster within a VM with 70 MiB of memory allocated to it. Curiously, it can boot and run fine, but panics when I try to shut it down.

Here is the log of the panic, which I captured over serial using [this guide](https://blog.wataash.com/ubuntu_console/).

```
[   13.862707] Out of memory: Kill process 162 (systemd-journal) score 30 or sacrifice child
[   13.864027] Killed process 162 (systemd-journal) total-vm:28632kB, anon-rss:1040kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:324kB
[   13.874500] Out of memory: Kill process 392 (systemd-udevd) score 20 or sacrifice child
[   13.875658] Killed process 392 (systemd-udevd) total-vm:21924kB, anon-rss:916kB, file-rss:24kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[   13.990890] Kernel panic - not syncing: System is deadlocked on memory
[   13.990890] 
[   13.992035] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: systemd-shutdow Not tainted 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1
[   13.993291] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.13.0-0-gf21b5a4aeb02-prebuilt.qemu.org 04/01/2014
[   13.994761] Call Trace:
[   13.995061]  dump_stack+0x66/0x90
[   13.995541]  panic+0xe7/0x24a
[   13.996081]  out_of_memory.cold.33+0x2f/0x82
[   13.996721]  __alloc_pages_slowpath+0xbd8/0xcb0
[   13.997255]  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x28b/0x2b0
[   13.997886]  filemap_fault+0x333/0x780
[   13.998409]  ? alloc_set_pte+0x49e/0x560
[   13.998926]  ? filemap_map_pages+0x1ed/0x3a0
[   13.999569]  ext4_filemap_fault+0x2c/0x40 [ext4]
[   14.000265]  __do_fault+0x36/0x130
[   14.000856]  __handle_mm_fault+0xe6c/0x1270
[   14.001644]  ? isolate_lru_page+0x1c7/0x260
[   14.002426]  handle_mm_fault+0xd6/0x200
[   14.003140]  __get_user_pages+0x23a/0x6c0
[   14.003908]  populate_vma_page_range+0x6d/0x70
[   14.004747]  __mm_populate+0x9d/0x140
[   14.005422]  __x64_sys_mlockall+0xf1/0x180
[   14.006191]  do_syscall_64+0x53/0x110
[   14.006889]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[   14.007823] RIP: 0033:0x7ff835b5f3c7
[   14.008494] Code: 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d c9 6a 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48 83 c8 ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 b8 97 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 99 6a 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[   14.011333] RSP: 002b:00007ffca4ff9128 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000097
[   14.012373] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00007ff835b5f3c7
[   14.013393] RDX: 0000000000008000 RSI: 000029b92070b2da RDI: 0000000000000003
[   14.014361] RBP: 0000563f14544420 R08: 000000000000021f R09: 0000563f15281290
[   14.016407] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
[   14.017351] R13: 00007ffca4ff94b0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[   14.018434] Kernel Offset: 0x39800000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[   14.020004] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: System is deadlocked on memory
[   14.020004]  ]---
```

Any ideas on how I can prevent it from panicking during shutdown, aside from giving it more memory?

Comment: 70MB is not enough for buster.   See [3.4. Meeting Minimum Hardware Requirements](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/ch03s04.en.html) - minimum RAM for buster without X is 256MB, recommended is 512.   If you really don't want to allocate 256MB to the VM, you might get away with 128MB or maybe 192MB.  Or maybe not.

Comment: @cas That manual also notes that "The actual minimum memory requirements are a lot less than the numbers listed in this table. With swap enabled, it is possible to install Debian with as little as 170MB."

Comment: yeah, and weird things happen when you try to run Linux without enough RAM.  The kernel's OOM killer will randomly kill processes when it runs out of memory, often resulting in bizarre behaviour.  Your question is evidence of that.   BTW, 70MB is significantly less than 170MB.

Comment: I'm not that bothered if the OOM killer kills processes during shutdown.